# Google Sheets Merging Cells

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a spreadsheet for the family tree.  There is one row for each person and successive people can have a date of marriage.  I would like to merge the cells in column F (the date of the marriage column) for the thousands of potential pairings.  The code I have is:-

```
function mergeMarriageCells() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i += 2) {
    ss.getRange(i, 5, 2, 1).mergeVertically();
  }
}
```

This gives me an error in line 6, the one which starts with ss.getRange.  The error it gives is:

> "Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match
> the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange. (line 6,
> file "Code")".

However, i has been initialised to 1 and should therefore be understood as an integer and not a string.

By the way, the first row contains the headings, hence the loop starts at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue:**

A [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getdatarange) object does not have a method [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column). The latter is a method of a [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) object.

---

**Solution:**

1. Modify your code to consider the **Sheet** instead of the
   **Spreadsheet**.

You have the following ways to do that:

```
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0] // 0 means first sheet, 1 means second sheet
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(); // the sheet that is currently selected in the file
```

Choose **one** of these three depending on what your goal is. See **References** section on what each of them does to find which suits you the best.

2. Finally, if you want to merge the cells in **column F**, then you need to choose `6` instead of `5` (**column E**) in the second argument of `getRange`.

---

**Result:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  // var sh = ss.getSheets()[0] // 0 means first sheet
  // var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(); // the sheet that is currently selected
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i += 2) {
    sh.getRange(i, 6, 2, 1).mergeVertically();
  }
  
}
```

Please modify `Sheet1` to your specific scenario.

---

**References:**

- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))
- [getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)
- [getActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactivesheet)

Comment: That worked first time and saved me literally hours.  Thank you so much for your help - it is really appreciated.  Your amendment let me update the sheets and do 9,500+ merges in less than two minutes,